# React: get property from clicked link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react tag that takes a url prop and turns the output into a link. Once that link is clicked, I create a bootstrap modal asking the user if they want to continue. I have a for loop creating multible tags for different links, and it makes the link with the url displayed. Clicking any of the urls also opens a modal box with some information, but the proceed button on my modal always links to the first element. Here is a video showing it in action: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlcKB.gif)

Here's the code for the ExternalUrl tag:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {tu} from "../../utils/i18n";

class ExternalUrl extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExternalUrlWarning">{this.props.url}</a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="ExternalUrlWarning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ExternalUrlWarning" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="ExternalUrlWarningLabel">External Link</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            {tu("The link")} <b> {this.props.url} </b> {tu("is not a verified site and therefore may not be secure. Proceed at your own risk.")} 
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href={this.props.url} target="_blank">{tu("Proceed")}</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{tu("Cancel")}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default ExternalUrl;
```

Here's that code that's using the ExternalUrl tag:

```
witnesses.map((account, index) => (
            <tr key={account.address}>
              <td><ExternalUrl url={account.url}></ExternalUrl></td>
            </tr>
          ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `id="ExternalUrlWarning"` in your `ExternalUrl` component.

You are looping over witnesses and generating multiple ExternalUrl components. But id will be same(ExternalUrlWarning) for all the modals.

Pass the index to the ExternalUrl component like this

```
witnesses.map((account, index) => (
        <tr key={account.address}>
          <td><ExternalUrl url={account.url} index={index}></ExternalUrl></td>
        </tr>
      ))
```

and use that to construct id of the modal.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target={"#ExternalUrlWarning_"+this.props.index}>{this.props.url}</a>

<div class="modal fade" id={"ExternalUrlWarning_"+this.props.index} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ExternalUrlWarning" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create an on click handler for your element and pass through the URL

```
witnesses.map((account, index) => (
  <tr key={account.address} onClick={() => this.handleClick(account.url)}>
    <td><ExternalUrl url={account.url}></ExternalUrl></td>
  </tr>
))

...

handleClick(url) {
    console.log('url', url)
    // handle your modal state here
}
```